# Windows (All) how to append date to end of new folder creation?

Tags: date, batch-file, piping

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new folder that has the date, not time, appended to the end of the directory  name. I just need the current time of creation, and nothing more.

Trying to use something really basic like the following as an example...

```
if exists CNC_%date% goto EXIST

if not exists CNC_%date% goto CREATE

:CREATE

mkdir CNC_%date%

:EXIST

echo Folder already exists!

echo Check directory and rename it to prevent loss of data.

echo.

echo Press any key to exit.

pause >nul

goto END

:CREATE

echo Creation successful!

echo Press any key to exit.

pause >nul

:END

exit
```

... results in the creation of a nested directory like `"C:\"CNC_Fri 11"\22\2013"` because of the backslashes.

IS there any way to pipe the backslashes through a native Windows program, and switch them with underscores? In Linux grep would have been my answer, but I need a native Windows method as this needs to be portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir cnc_%date:/=_%
```

Use the date variable with the slashs replaced with underscore

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before, what is that called?

Comment: variable substring replacement or any variation meaning the same. `%date%` is the variable. The sintax used is `%varName:searchString=replaceString%`. That way, slash is replaced with underscore.